# How to append multiple values under the same property key?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have multiple projects that expose a Prometheus endpoint, like so:
Application1: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,prometheus`
Application2: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,metrics,prometheus`
Application3: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,refresh,prometheus`

Instead of adding this Prometheus config to each application separately, I have extracted this to a separate library and added it as a dependency. The lib's `application.properties` file only consists `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus`.

Whenvever I start up my applications, all of their config is overwritten with `prometheus`, instead of the value being added to the back of the list.

Is it possible to append multiple values to the same key instead of it being overwritten?

Comment: No. Even worse only 1 `application.properties` can be loaded, it doesn't load all the `application.properties` files on the classpath, only the first detected. Instead write an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` which adds `prometheus` (and info?) to this property instead.

Comment: hmmm well, I tested it by just adding `test=test` to the lib's `application.properties` and it gets picked up by all the applications, complementary to their own configuration.

Comment: Not if those have an `application.properties` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum You were right, I had `application.properties`, `application.yml` and `application.yaml`. I guess that's why they got loaded in separately. I'm trying the solution with `EnvironmentPostProcessor` as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use profiles feature. Profiles means that you can run the same project with different profiles where each profile can have its own property files and even different bean implementations per profile. Read this article about profiles and see if that will help: [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: That doesn't seem like an elegant solution. What you're saying is that I can end up with an annotation that looks like `@Profile({"dev","prometheus","mysql","logging","interceptors","generics",...}`?
I thought profiles were to distinguish different environments :/

Comment: Yes, Like it or not that is personal feeling, but it is a standard way to resolve stuff like this